# How does getline() evaluate as true or false in a while loop condition?

Tags: c++

For example `while(getline( , ))`

when is this kind of condition true/false and why are they used instead of other situational conditions?

Comment: Did you look at documentation for the `getline` function?

Comment: This condition is true when `getline()` returns a true value.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your questions will be better received if they pertain to a topic that isn't something you can simply look up in any reference manual. Please read the [**About**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) page soon and also visit the links describing [**How to Ask a Question**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Providing the necessary details, including your code, and associated errors, if any, will allow everyone here to help you with your question.

Comment: If the condition evaluates to `true` or `false` depends on the streams state that is returned by the [`std::getline()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) function. Basically this is determined by the overloaded [operator for casting to bool](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool) @melpomene.

Comment: @David How does that question require a [MCVE]?

Comment: Also the close vote is completely unjustifiable here. The question is neither _unclear_, nor _too broad_. Looking at the `std::getline()` documentation doesn't explain that behavior obviously.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I think it's unclear. *instead of other* - like what?

Comment: That was the point -- if the question doesn't require a MCVE -- it's not really a question...

Comment: @David _"if the question doesn't require a MCVE -- it's not really a question."_ Sorry, I strongly disagree with you about that.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Questions (even ones about actual code) don't always require an MCVE.

Comment: [Only debugging questions require code.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/338846/2891664) Also [*Is there really a universal code requirement?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/291399/2891664) and [*Do we need a close reason for zero-effort questions?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260828/2891664)

Comment: I had no idea that you could or were supposed to have `while (std::getline(etc.))` specifically _because_ I had relied on so heavily on documentation.  I only found out about that pretty recently, myself.

Comment: @hegel5000 Which confirms that this question is useful for future research. Thank you for the feedback!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> when is this kind of condition true/false

Given the [documentation of `std::getline()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) which says the return value is the `std::istream` reference of the stream that is involved in the operation, it isn't obvious how that stream evaluates to `true` or `false`.

This is done using the overloaded [cast operator to `bool`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool) inherited from the `std::ios` class.
This class defines the state flags indicating the current stream state, and `true` will be only evaluated if the stream state is `good`, other states like `eof` or `fail` will evaluate to `false`.

---

> and why are they used instead of other situational conditions?

Highly related Q&A: [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong)