# Why can't I return std::getline's as-if-boolean result?

Tags: c++, boolean, ifstream

A standard idiom is

```
while(std::getline(ifstream, str))
    ...
```

So if that works, why can't I say

```
bool getval(std::string &val)
{
    ...

    std::ifstream infile(filename);

    ...

    return std::getline(infile, val);
}
```

g++ says "`cannot convert 'std::basic_istream<char>' to 'bool' in return`".

Is the Boolean context of a `return` statement in a `bool`-valued function somehow different from the Boolean context of `while()`, such that the [magic conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51128037) that `std::basic_istream` performs in one context doesn't work in the other?

---

Addendum: There's apparently some version and perhaps language standard dependency here.  I got the aforementioned error with g++ 8.3.0.  But I don't get it with gcc 4.6.3, or LLVM (clang) 9.0.0.

Comment: hmm, works with a cast, but not implicitly - paging c++ level 5 wizards

Comment: `return !!std::getline(infile, val);` would be an option

Comment: Precious few questions pique my interest as much as this one, good one. I look forward to seeing the answers since the compiler has all information needed to know it has to end up as a boolean.

Comment: OT:  @TedLyngmo Well, maybe it would be better something more "explicit": `return std::getline(infile, val).good();`

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The [boolean conversion operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool) for `std::basic_istream` is `explicit`. This means that instances of the type will not implicitly become a `bool` but can be converted to one explicitly, for instance by typing `bool(infile)`.

Explicit boolean conversion operators are considered for conditional statements, i.e. the expression parts of `if`, `while` etc. More info about contextual conversions [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Contextual_conversions).

However, a return statement will not consider the `explicit` conversion operators or constructors. So you have to explicitly convert that to a boolean for a `return`.

Comment: so 'explicit' conversions sometimes arent

Comment: Thank you.  `explicit` is one of those diminishing-return nuances that my poor old brain doesn't consider important enough to learn, but slapping `bool(...)` around my `std::getline()` call seems to be working.

Comment: 'when initializing a new object of type T2, including return statement in a function returning T2;' - that's in the docs, why does it not apply here?

Comment: @SteveSummit there's the old `!!` trick too.  operand of `!`  counts as "explicit" conversion to bool

Comment: @paxdiablo, that is only for implicit conversions. In C++ those will be constructors and operators not marked `explicit`.

Comment: @M.M Ted Lyngmo suggested that, too.  That's probably what I would have tried next, without Fatih's answer.  But the question here was "Why doesn't this work?", not "What can I use instead?".

Comment: Sorry, damn ipad posted my comment early. The rest was that it also has 'when the expression is used in an if statement or a loop (T2 is bool).'. Surely that covers the while case? Or am I missing something?

Comment: In other words, it looks like 'while' should also not consider explicit converters. ???

Comment: Never mind, just followed your link for the contextual conversions. The stuff I found seems to state where implicit conversion happens rather than where explicit conversions cannot. Your other link clarifies the distinction. Good answer.

Comment: @M.M "*operand of ! counts as "explicit" conversion to bool*" - except in this case, since `istream` has an [`operator!`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator!) implemented.

Comment: Instead of using the C-style cast `bool(...)` shouldn't we use `static_cast<bool>(...)` instead?

Comment: @infinitezero, `static_cast` debate aside, I think the C-style cast would be `(bool)...`, AFAIK `bool(...)` is C++-only.

Comment: Took me some searching but the `bool(...)` syntax is a form of https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast (point (2)): it translates directly to a C-style cast and is only usable for 1 word types. So, yeah for both those reasons I do think a static_cast seems more appropriate.